# Deconvolution Layer does not accept 5D blobs with bilinear filler

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

Does anyone have a workaround for that problem? Any other filler options which might be similar? Or shall I just omit the filler weight option?

Comment: You can always fill a layer manually from outside. Eg: lookout how they fill deconv layer with bilinear coefficients (line : 23)

Comment: Have you got a reference for your "line 23"? @AbidRahmanK

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to provide the link: https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org/blob/master/voc-fcn8s/solve.py#L23

Comment: Is there no other way to fix this problem in `.prototxt`? @AbidRahmanK

Comment: Could you answer my question properly so I could give you credit? When looking at the link I cannot really see the code for filling the layer. @AbidRahmanK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have adjusted the file [github](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org/blob/master/voc-fcn8s/solve.py#L23) so that it performs a bilinear filling for 5D blobs:

```
def upsample_filt(size):
        """
        Make a 2D bilinear kernel suitable for upsampling of the given (h, w) size.
        """
        factor = (size + 1) // 2
        if size % 2 == 1:
            center = factor - 1
        else:
            center = factor - 0.5
        og = np.ogrid[:size, :size, :size]

        return (1 - abs(og[0] - center) / factor) * \
               (1 - abs(og[1] - center) / factor) * \
               (1 - abs(og[2] - center) / factor)

def interp(net, layers):
    """
    Set weights of each layer in layers to bilinear kernels for interpolation.
    """
    for l in layers:
        m, k, d, h, w = net.params[l][0].data.shape

        if m != k and k != 1:
            print('input + output channels need to be the same or |output| == 1')
            raise
        if h != w or h != d or w != d:
            print('filters need to be square')
            raise
        filt = upsample_filt(h)
        net.params[l][0].data[range(m), range(k), :, :, :] = filt


caffe.set_device(0)
caffe.set_mode_gpu()

solver = caffe.SGDSolver('solver.prototxt')

# surgeries
interp_layers = [k for k in solver.net.params.keys() if 'Deconv' in k]
interp(solver.net, interp_layers)

#print(interp_layers)

solver.solve();
```